# Cross-Reference Array elements bei named index - PHP/Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

TL;DR:
I want to use data from a 1-dimensional array of arbitrary size, created by userinput, and fill its values into the appropriate fields of a 2-dimensional array of arbitrary size, created via query from the Database.

I have a webapplication where the user can access the DBs data both in read-mode and write-mode. 
The DB records accessible to him are determined by the departments he belongs to. 
The records are organized in a DB structure where a coretable contains data visible to ALL departments, while extensiontables referencing the coretable via FK contain data which are only visible to users who belong to the department associated with this extensiontable.

I'm using Lumen/Laravel and its eloquent model to interact with the DB from my Backend, some examplecode for accessing the DB looks like this:

```
$join = coretable::with($permittedTables)->find(1);
```

Here, `$permittedTables` is an array of tablenames, referencing the extensiontables accessible to the user.

The above code then fetches the following result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_1",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_iTC_1"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_1"
  }
}
```

Now, the user will have a list-like view in the front-end where all this data has been merged into a big table. In this list, the user can click a field and change its value, then send an http-request to persist these changes to the DB. 
This http-request will be an array in JSON format, which i will `json_decode()` in my backend, and use the transmitted `id` to fetch the model as seen above.

Now, at this point, two sets of data, organized in the structure of associative arrays, will face each other. The input from the http-request will likely be a 1-dimensional array, while the model from the DB will almost certainly be the multidimensional array youve seen above. 
Furthermore, there is a huge amount of possible combinations of datasets. It can be the combination seen above, but it also can be a combination of data from other tables not listed here, and it can be both a bigger or smaller set of tables aggregated into the model and userinput. 
Therefore, the process setting the incoming input to the DB must be able to determine dynamically which field of the input must be put into which field of the DB.

I'm doing this for the first time and I don't have a lot of ideas how to do this. The only thing that came to my mind was mirroring the DB column names to the indexes of the input's array and then loop through the model and compare its indexes to the index of the currently selected element of the input. If they match, the value from the respective field of the input will be set to the respective field of the DB. 
I am aware that in order for this to work, each column of the tables affected by this process MUST have a unique name across the DB. This is doable though.
Still, this is currently the only idea I could come up with.

However, I wanted to ask you two things about this:
1) Are there other, less "hacky" approaches to solve the problem outlined above?
2) Can someone give me a custom function/a set of custom functions capable of iterating over two arrays, of which at least one will be multidimensional, while comparing their indexes, then setting the value from `Array A` to `Array B` when the indexes match?

Below I have a little codeexample, creating two arrays which reproduce the described situation, with which you can fiddle around:

First, the inputside:

```
$inputArray = array( 
            "id" => 1,
            "internal_key" => "TESTKEY_1",
            "CPU" => "intelTest1",
            "GPU" => "nvidiaTest1", 
            "Soundcard" => "AsusTest1"
            "MAC" => "macTest1",
            "IP" => "ipTest1",
            "VLAN" => "vlanTest1"
            );
```

Then, the DB-side:

```
$modelArray = array( 
            "id" => 1,
            "internal_key" => "TESTKEY_2",
            "extensiontable_itc" => array (
                                  "CPU" => "intelTest1",
                                  "GPU" => "nvidiaTest2",   
                                  "Soundcard" => "AsusTest1"
        ),

        "extensiontable_sysops" => array (
                                 "MAC" => "macTest2",
                                 "IP" => "ipTest1",
                                 "VLAN" => "vlanTest1"
         )
 );
```

Comment: I would suggest slimming your question down or at least adding a **TL;DR** as I imagine many people will see the length of this and not want to read through it.

Comment: @Rwd added the TL;DR, hope it helps! :)