# "Sync" 2D Array with 1D Array By matching Keys - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

A one dimensional array:

```
$oneDimArray= array( 
            "id" => 1,
            "internal_key" => "TESTKEY_1",
            "CPU" => "intelTest1",
            "GPU" => "nvidiaTest1", 
            "Soundcard" => "AsusTest1"
            "MAC" => "macTest1",
            "IP" => "ipTest1",
            "VLAN" => "vlanTest1"
            );
```

And a two dimensional array:

```
$twoDimArray= array( 
                    "id" => 1,
                    "internal_key" => "TESTKEY_2",
                    "nestedArray1" => array (
                                             "CPU" => "intelTest1",
                                             "GPU" => "nvidiaTest2",   
                                             "Soundcard" => "AsusTest1"
          ),

                    "nestedArray2" => array (
                                             "MAC" => "macTest2",
                                             "IP" => "ipTest1",
                                             "VLAN" => "vlanTest1"
         )
 );
```

I want a function which takes two arrays, one is OneDimensional and the other TwoDimensional.
It iterates over every element of the OneDimensional array, and for each of these elements, it also iterates over all elements of the TwoDimensional array.
For each element of the TwoDimensional array it compares the key of the currently selected element of the OneDimensional array to the key of the currently selected element of the TwoDimensional array. 
Should these keys match, the function writes the value of the currently selected element of the OneDimensional Array to the currently selected element of the TwoDimensional array.

For the endresult, the TwoDimensional Array should be preserved (its "instance", so to say) but have its elements updated accordingly with the data coming from the OneDimensional Array.

EDIT: I found the answer myself, could you please reopen the question so I can post it? :)

Comment: First of all, this is not a code-writing service. Do you have any attempt to show us?

Comment: And what do you want to “compare” here anyway? If you say the data should be _updated_ - then _overwrite_ it, at which point would this need _comparing_ of anything?

Comment: This appears to be pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071856/cross-reference-array-elements-bei-named-index-php-laravel-lumen anyway, which you asked just two hours ago.

Comment: @04FS Well, is there any convenient, built-in php method to overwrite a 2D array with a 1D array? If so, please tell me about it and I will use it. 
But if there is not, then I need to compare the elements by their key and value, otherwise any Elements value will be written to any Elements value, completely jumbling the datas structure.

Furthermore, it would be nice if the optional goal could be met to also succeed in updating the 2D array from a 1D array with less non-array elements than the 2D-array has.

Comment: @04FS yes the questions revolve around the same problem, but they ask from different perspectives. The first one was asking for a solution in context laravel and its eloquent ORM. The second here wants to solve the problem with plain php. I didn't receive any answer on my first one, thus I assume nobody has the knowledge to provide me with an answer utilizing laravel and eloquent. But there still might be people around being able to help me with plain php, and thats why I opened this question.

Comment: No, there is no built-in method to handle such arbitrary data objects, that for some unexplained reason vary in their structure so significantly.

Comment: Your first version of it wasn’t really that laravel-specific to begin with, you aren’t even operating with collections or anything, you have just shown some plain arrays. And not having an answer after a mere two hours is not a valid excuse for a duplicate either.

Comment: @04FS is that reason so important? Because I dont think it is considering the scope of the question. This is the situation I'm facing and its been abstracted to a minimal, easier to understand example.

Comment: Still unclear what you even mean, when you say you need to compare the key _and_ the value. If the keys _and_ the values would still be the same - then you would not have any actual _update_ in the first place.

Comment: @04FS The first question was laravel specific, if you read through it you will see that there is a model instance at play there -.- And you can easily turn this into a collection if you just swap ->find() to ->findMany().

Comment: @04FS Then I will edit my question to make the goal of comparing key and value clearer. What I want is that VALUES are only compared for difference if their KEYS match. Only in this case the value from OneDimArray shall replace the respective value inside TwoDimArray.

Comment: Comparing the values still makes little in that kind of scenario. You identify the correct location / data element, based on its key - and then you simply overwrite the existing value, with the “new” one. If that is still the same as the existing one, then effectively nothing has changed, and if it is not, then you have performed an _actual_ update. Introducing an extra step of “comparing” the two first, makes little sense.

Comment: @04FS oh, yeah youre right :D 
Then youre indeed right that comparing the values in a second step is unnecessary to achieve my goal^^

Comment: It is the best to simply ask the question, for example I want this. It is difficult to read and understand your question.

Comment: @Dilek yeah youre right, I just changed the original OP and removed all the stuff that has become obsolete now that I know better through 04FS advice. Thanks!

Comment: So! The simple question is, you want to compare both arrays and create a new array from both arrays right ? do I get right ?

Comment: @Dilek First part, Yes: I want to compare both arrays as described in OP. 
Second part, not quite: I want to keep the twodimensional array, but I want to update it with the data from the onedimensional array

Comment: @04FS I think I found my answer myself! Could we reopen the question so I can post my answer? This way I could also have people review (and maybe test) my answer, but I think I got it right! :D

Comment: (Voted to re-open, but it’s gonna need one more vote before it actually happens.)

Comment: It's reopened now, feel free to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I made it!
Here is the function necessary to do the job:

```
  public function recursiveUpdateArray($b1, &$b2, $b1val = null){
    /**
    *
    * @param  array $b1 -> One-Dimensional Array
    * @param  array $b2 as reference -> Two-Dimensional Array or Model which then gets converted to array
    * @param  string $b1val -> currently selected value of $b1 array before recursion
    *
    *
    ***/

    if(!is_array($b2)){
      $b2 = $b2->toArray();
    }


    if(is_array($b1)){
      foreach($b1 as $bkeyOneDimensional => $bvalOneDimensional){
        foreach($b2 as $bkeyTwoDimensional => &$bvalTwoDimensional){

          if(is_array($bvalTwoDimensional)){
             $this->recursiveUpdateArray($bkeyOneDimensional, $bvalTwoDimensional, $bvalOneDimensional);
          }elseif($bkeyOneDimensional === $bkeyTwoDimensional){
            $bvalTwoDimensional = $bvalOneDimensional;
          }
        }
      }
    }elseif(is_string($b1) && is_array($b2)){
      foreach($b2 as $b2key => &$b2val){
        if($b1 === $b2key){
          $b2val = $b1val;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

And here is how you would have to call it inside your workflow:

```
recursiveUpdateArray($oneDimArray, $toBeUpdatedTwoDimArray);
```

Since the function takes in your `$toBeUpdatedTwoDimArray` as a reference, you don't need to return into anything, the twoDimArray will have received the updates automatically after the function has finished.